# Setting border's width as the same as the text width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a menu that I designed with a website builder. It was custom CSS but the HTML is created automatically with the builder. I used inspect to get the following code:

```
<div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-no">
            <div class="elementor-row">
            <div data-id="27de853d" class="elementor-element elementor-element-27de853d elementor-column elementor-col-11 elementor-top-column" data-element_type="column">
        <div class="elementor-column-wrap">
                <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
            <div data-id="52e1a94f" class="elementor-element elementor-element-52e1a94f elementor-column elementor-col-11 elementor-top-column" data-element_type="column">
        <div class="elementor-column-wrap">
                <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
            <div data-id="2968abde" class="elementor-element elementor-element-2968abde elementor-column elementor-col-11 elementor-top-column" data-element_type="column">
        <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
            <div data-id="f6e51ca" class="elementor-element elementor-element-f6e51ca menu-item elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="menuu" data-element_type="heading.default">
            <div class="elementor-widget-container">
        <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#contact"><p dir="rtl">צור קשר<span style="font-family: Heebo, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; font-weight: 500;"></span></p></a></h4>     </div>
            </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
            <div data-id="43e9a7ba" class="elementor-element elementor-element-43e9a7ba elementor-column elementor-col-11 elementor-top-column" data-element_type="column">
        <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
            <div data-id="a306aa1" class="elementor-element elementor-element-a306aa1 menu-item elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="menuu" data-element_type="heading.default">
            <div class="elementor-widget-container">
        <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#thesolutions"><p dir="rtl">פתרונות<span style="font-family: Heebo, sans-serif; font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: 500; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);"></span></p></a></h4>     </div>
            </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
            <div data-id="462f96df" class="elementor-element elementor-element-462f96df elementor-column elementor-col-11 elementor-top-column" data-element_type="column">
        <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
            <div data-id="426ca1f7" class="elementor-element elementor-element-426ca1f7 menu-item elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="menuu" data-element_type="heading.default">
            <div class="elementor-widget-container">
        <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#fit"><p dir="rtl">למי זה מתאים?<span style="font-family: Heebo, sans-serif; font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: 500; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);"></span></p></a></h4>        </div>
            </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
            <div data-id="573bf04" class="elementor-element elementor-element-573bf04 elementor-column elementor-col-11 elementor-top-column" data-element_type="column">
        <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
            <div data-id="209f237" class="elementor-element elementor-element-209f237 menu-item elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="menuu" data-element_type="heading.default">
            <div class="elementor-widget-container">
        <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#aboutus"><p dir="rtl">אודות<span style="font-family: Heebo, sans-serif; font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: 500; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);"></span></p></a></h4>        </div>
            </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
            <div data-id="255c8355" class="elementor-element elementor-element-255c8355 elementor-column elementor-col-11 elementor-top-column" data-element_type="column">
        <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
            <div data-id="2e919436" class="elementor-element elementor-element-2e919436 menu-item elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="menuu" data-element_type="heading.default">
            <div class="elementor-widget-container">
        <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#regulation"><p dir="rtl">מהי רגולציה?<span style="font-family: Heebo, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; font-weight: 500;"></span></p></a></h4>     </div>
            </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
            <div data-id="6d524b7b" class="elementor-element elementor-element-6d524b7b elementor-column elementor-col-11 elementor-top-column" data-element_type="column">
        <div class="elementor-column-wrap">
                <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
            <div data-id="3063bb4b" class="elementor-element elementor-element-3063bb4b elementor-column elementor-col-11 elementor-top-column" data-element_type="column">
        <div class="elementor-column-wrap">
                <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
                    </div>
        </div>

#menuu {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0B1B70;
  -webkit-transition: border 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: border 200ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: border 200ms ease-out;
  transition: border 200ms ease-out;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 3px 0;
  height: 30px
}

#menuu:hover,
#menuu:focus,
#menuu:active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #61f6ff;
  border-top: 2px solid #61f6ff;
}

.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #61f6ff !important;
  border-top: 2px solid #61f6ff !important;
}
```

I want the border's width to always be affected by the length of the text (the border shouldn't be longer than text but exactly the width of the text). How can I use CSS for that? I tried to use inline block but it messes with the menu and it cancels all the functionality of it.

Here's a link to this page: http://mayabarber.co.il/

Comment: Hi Rozi, welcome to SO please could you include your html too and create a [mcve] demonstrating your current problem

Comment: It would be nice to have the contextual HTML to this problem.

Comment: Hi I apologize for the inconvenience. The website was created with a live builder so I didn't actually create this HTML. I used inspect and updated the HTML now, and I have also added a link so you can see it yourself.

Comment: The link to the temporary page is not working.

Comment: Here's the regular page- http://mayabarber.co.il/ I'm talking about the menu at the top of the page, in the main sticky header.
I have also updated the main post. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score -1):

What you want is to use inline-block for your menu, so that it has the width assigned by the content width.

```
display: inline-block
```

If this won't solve your problem please post your html as well.

Comment: Hi I apologize for the inconvenience. The website was created with a live builder so I didn't actually create this HTML. I used inspect and updated the HTML now, and I have also added a link so you can see it yourself. The inline-block solution is something I thought of but it's messing with the menu. Can you please take a look at the updated information?

Thanks for willing to help!